# Virtual burner like Phantom Drive for Linux OS?

Tags: ubuntu, burning

On Windows, I used [Phantom Drive](http://www.phantom-drive.com/) or Virtual CD to emulate a burner. I was able to "burn CDs" into an ISO file without wasting a CD-R.

I would like to do this in Ubuntu as well. Does anyone know a suitable tool or any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which format are you burning from that you must burn to an emulated burner in order to get an iso (9660)? If you're just burning files already on your file system, just use mkisofs, it creates an iso9660 file for you. If you're using some kind of Bin/Cue or some other format, you're actually looking to convert the format to an iso9660.

The only (rare) cases where there's a call for a virtual burner are the ones where you have some proprietary software that only supports burning it's output to a CD or DVD in a drive and will not let you save an image first. If this is the case, you might specify which software you're using under linux that limits you like this, and perhaps someone can suggest an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=329708) can help you out. It mentions Gnomebaker, k3b, and quite a lot of other options.

Comment: I need an application that is included in all authoring software. The thread starter over there wants the same and is misunderstood, too.

Answer (score 0):

mkisofs -- check [LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch),
and, [How-To Make Ubuntu DVDs Including Main, the Universe and Everything](http://www.entner.net/blog/how-to-make-ubuntu-dvds-including-main-the-universe-and-everything)
These links discuss making LiveCD images, but you can probably pull the necessary usage.

Answer (score -1):

You can just mount an ISO file and access information on it as if it was a real CD-ROM: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-mount-iso-image-under-linux.html